# Can not connect to the MongoDB database using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have one issue.I have one login application while i am trying to login by using email and password the following error is coming.

> Error:

```
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
 Error: connect UNKNOWN 127.0.0.1:27017 - Local (undefined:undefined)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at connect (net.js:843:14)
    at net.js:939:9
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

I am explaining my code below.

> route.js:

```
var mongo=require('mongojs');
var database='db_docs';
var collections=['admin','supplier'];
var db=mongo("127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
exports.login=function(req,res){
    var email=req.body.user_name;
    var pass=req.body.user_pass;
    db.admin.findOne({
        email:email,
        actual_password:pass
    },function(err,docs){
        if(docs){
            var ses=req.session;
            ses.email=docs.email;
            ses.usertype=docs.usertype;
            ses.name=docs.name;
            res.send(docs);
        }
        if(err){
            res.send('Could not login');
        }
    })
}
```

Here my MongoDB database is also running in the same ip and port number.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: didnt any code problems, did you start mongo server ?

Comment: @trquoccuong : yes i have started my mongoDB but still there is issue.

Comment: try : mongo(database,collection)  or full connstring "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/+database

Comment: @trquoccuong : no same error is coming after applying your method also.